# Linking between two word documents in a folder than doesn't have a static location.

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm working on a training guide using Word 2016 and I have other word files I want to link to with important information on them, however the location of the directory isn't guarenteed to be in the same location since it will need to be downloaded by the reader. How can I make sure that the hyperlinks that are going to be in my document no matter where it is located. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little clarification needed- do you mean the other word files will be in a different directory than the training guide, or just that the directory with the training guide may be in a different place?

If the latter, you simply want to use relative hyperlinks. There's a MS help doc that I'll link at the end with the full information, but the short version is, you simply start the address from the location of the document you're in. So instead of C:\Users\documents\guide\suppliment1 you would just use \suppliment1 and assuming it's in the same directory as your host document, it would work.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu

NB: If it's the former, there's not a very simple way to do that afaik.

Comment: Just the document directory being in a different place. All the word files will be in the same directory.

Comment: Yup, then my solution should be exactly what you need. Good luck!